# Change whole folder from http to https

Tags: magento-1.8, htaccess, https, apache2

The checkout/onepage is working with https. But, why checkout/cart is not?

Please see the detail in the following link.
http://pastebin.com/ASNZMixJ

Answer (score 1):

If you want `https` secure page you follow below method(work on local don't edit core file)

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml
```

FInd this

```
<frontend>
<secure_url>
```

after that you add in below mention way

```
<frontend>
<secure_url>
<checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>
<checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
<checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
</secure_url>
```

Then clear cache and session then check

Comment: my onepage have https, do I still need to add it in the secure_url?

Comment: need not try only cart

Comment: I added those three lines in <secure_url>, yet the checkout/cart is still not work with https.

Comment: solved my problem with cart message block thanks.

Answer (score 1):

simply overwrite magento defaults:

app/etc/modules/MyModule_CartSecure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_CartSecure>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyModule_CartSecure>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyModule/CartSecure/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_CartSecure/>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>
            <checkout>/checkout/cart</checkout>
        </secure_url>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

or you can go to  System -> Configuration -> Web
and use https for unsecure base url, then all your pages will be https://

Comment: I added the <secure_url>...</secure_url>, it did not work.
See: app/code/local/Sns/Ajaxcart/etc/config.xml
http://pastebin.com/GjGpqNwX

Comment: And see: app/etc/modules/Sns_Ajaxcart.xml
http://pastebin.com/Tfc77dqR